# jQuery dataTables : Editing the Text in FixedColumn

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying the edit the content in the Fixed Column in the Datatable. I can able to edit the other rows in the Datatable,thats working but this is not working to the Fixed column content.

I have tried to give classes to that rows of Fixed column, but still it doesnt works.. 
Can anybody help me out this...

```
var oTable2 = $('#example2').dataTable({
        "sScrollX": "160%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
        iDisplayLength: 6,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aaData": [],
}); 

new FixedColumns( oTable2, {
            "iLeftColumns": 4,
            "iLeftWidth": 550
            }); 
$(".DTFC_LeftWrapper .DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper .display td:last-child ").addClass( "editableRow" );

    $('td.editableRow', oTable2.fnGetNodes()).editable( '../examples_support/editable_ajax.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable2.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable2.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable2.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        }
    });
```

The HTML will be basic table and the content is loading from a json or like from aadata.

```
<table id="example2"></table>
```

Comment: Post html/script code  what you have tried so far..

Comment: post the html code also.it will be helpful find the issue.

Comment: @MaheshMajeti There is nothing to say on the HTML end. The Html will be the basic <table id="example"></table>. Iam getting the editing to other cells in Table but except Fixed columns.

Comment: how r u defining it as fixed?

Comment: @MaheshMajeti I have added the full code for the Datatable...

Comment: @MaheshMajeti I have added the code, Can you help me out in this issue

Comment: what is datatable with example2 id  and ? ARe you using any plug in for datatable fixed column and other operations.?

Comment: the example2 is the table for the Datatable and i used the fixedcolumn of the datatable to make it fixed...

Comment: Hi @Khirthan, did u found a solution on this, I know its 5 Years down the line.